# Keep context after eval

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/Neb9E/

```
// Unknown parent
var Func=function(){}
Func.prototype.foo=function(){
    console.log(this,arguments);
}
window.func=new Func();


// External call, we do not know parent of evaled function
var foo=eval('func.foo');
foo();
window.func.foo();​
```

Is it possible to get the same result as calling `window.func.foo();​` when using eval?

Comment: [`eval` is *evil*!](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with eval.  When you say

```
foo();
```

`this` inside of foo will *always* be the global object (unless the function was created with `bind` -- see below).  You have a few choices:

You can "pre-set" the this value with `bind`

```
//won't work on IE8 - will have to shim `bind`
var foo = eval('func.foo.bind(func)');
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Neb9E/1/)

or you can manually set the `this` value when you call the function by using `call`

```
var foo = eval('func.foo');
foo.call(func);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Neb9E/2/)

---

And yes, as nbrooks said, use of eval should be discouraged.

Comment: Can't find sources for _evalJS. ExternalInterface sources of Actionscript are showing that _evalJS is actually calling the js code saving it's context. Anyone knows how it's doing it or link sources of it?

Comment: @Somebody - no idea.  The above should be the simplest way to control `this` inside of a function call.

Comment: Like i said, i don't have access to parent object(func).